# Sales Force Joomla

Tags: joomla, salesforce

Within Joomla were using RSForm then passing the data through to SalesForce eveything works apart from I'm using a html hidden field then trying to pass this through to sales force to check a checkbox... But can't get it working any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem...

It requires a 1